# How to use constants in loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I know this is dumb, but I need the equivalent of `np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)` in my loss function. How can I get it?  Statements like this give error: 'float object has no attribute dtype':

```
pi = np.pi
def myLoss(...):
   k = K.sqrt(2.0*pi)
   ...
```

Even `K.sqrt(2.0*3.14159)` is disallowed.

Comment: You're passing float instead of a tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
k = K.sqrt(tf.constant([2.0*np.pi]))
```

Since, it accepts an object which has dtype. One option is a Tensor.

Another option is to not using keras backend, but using numpy:

```
k = np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)
```